# Equivalent definitions of primary ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Here are two definitions of a primary ideal.

1. An ideal $I\subset A$ is primary if $I\ne A$ and $xy\in I\implies$ either $x\in I$ or $y^n\in I$ for some $n> 0$.
2. An ideal $I\subset A$ is primary if $Ass(A/I)$ consists of a single element.

Are they equivalent?

$2.\implies1.$ Suppose $Ass(A/I)$ consists of a single element $P$. If $I=A$, then I believe $Ass(A/I)=Ass(\{0\})$. The zero ring has no prime ideals, so there are no associated primes of the element $0$ in the zero ring. This contradiction shows that $I\ne A$. But I don't know how to deduce the other condition.

I don't have ideas for the other implication either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $A$ is Noetherian.

$1\implies 2$. Suppose $I$ is a proper ideal such that if $xy\in I$, then either $x\in I$ or $y^n\in I$ for some $n>0$.

Then if $P$ is associated to $A/I$, there exists $x\not \in I$ in $A$ such that $P$ is the annihilator of $x$ in $A/I$. I.e., $Px\subseteq I$, but this implies that $$I\subseteq P\subseteq \sqrt{I},$$ so $\sqrt{I}=P$. Thus the only possible associated prime of $A/I$ is $\sqrt{I}$, and since $A/I$ is nonzero, it has an associated prime. Thus $\operatorname{Ass} A/I$ consists of a single element, $\sqrt{I}$.

$2\implies 1$. Suppose $\operatorname{Ass} A/I$ consists of a single element. Then if $xy\in I$, with $x\not\in I$, then $y$ annihilates the image of $x$ in $A/I$, so $y$ lies in some associated prime, necessarily the unique associated prime of $A/I$, $P$. Since every ideal minimal over $I$ is associated to $A/I$, $P$ is the unique minimal prime over $I$, and therefore $P=\sqrt{I}$. Thus since $y\in P$, $y^n\in I$ for some $n$.

Comment: And I realized that this question is a duplicate, but oh well.

Comment: How did you get the chain $I\subseteq P\subseteq \sqrt{I}$? Shouldn't it be $I\subseteq \sqrt{I}\subseteq P\subseteq I$?

Comment: $I\subseteq P$, since $P$ is the annihilator of an element of $A/I$. Then for all $y\in P$, $yx\in I$, and $x\not \in I$, so $y^n\in I$. Thus $y\in\sqrt{I}$. Thus $P\subseteq \sqrt{I}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I also don't understand why every ideal minimal over $I$ is associated to $A/I$ (I only know that any prime ideal minimal over $Ann(A/I)$ is associated to $A/I$), and how it follows that $P$ is the unique minimal prime over $I$...

Comment: @user437309 The annihilator of $A/I$ is just $I$.

Comment: Well, if every prime minimal over $I$ is in $\operatorname{Ass} A/I=\{P\}$, then that tells you that $P$ is the unique minimal prime over $I$.